# Rename files in a directory based off of the text contained within a text file

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I am trying to rename about 20 files in a directory based off of what a text file contains. I have been searching around and cant really find anything that really describes the process. All the original files are like this:

```
Track 1.wav
Track 2.wav
```

etc...

I would like to rename them to this, which is typed out in a text file, with the name I would like for the file line by line.

```
We are Yours
Awake my Love
```

etc..

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I do it quite a bit but I end up doing it manually and it has just gotten old.

Comment: Could very well be done, but how to make sure the right name ends up with the right file? Are the filenames and lines in the same order? (And what is the order?)

Comment: The files in the directory are in order from 1 to 20. I have typed up the names in the same order so track 1 is we are yours, 2 is awake my love etc... I was thinking of running a loop to cycle through each file, read the top line of the text file IE We are Yours and then rename the file. Then on the second iteration read the next line of the text file, IE Awake my love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
n=1
while IFS= read -r newname; do
  printf -v oldname 'Track %d.wav' $((n++)) 
  echo mv -vn "$oldname" "$newname"
done < "filenames.txt"
```

where `filenames.txt` is the name of the file into which you typed the desired new names.

*If it seems to be doing the right thing then remove the `echo` and run it again to actually rename the files*

Comment: Thanks that worked flawlessly. I put it into a script to run whenever I need. Can you explain the 'Track %d.wav' $((n++)) part? I get the Track being enclosed in single brackets but I dont get the %d part. Thanks again, you definitely made life a bit better.

Comment: The `%d` is a (decimal integer) *format specifier* for the bash shell's `printf` built-in: type `help printf` - or  `man printf` for even more gory detail

Comment: This was really good. I just renamed 250 movies files to their correct titles with this. But a couple of things. I had to add the `.mp4` extension using a batch renamer because the script made the files extensionless. Here's my the code: `n=1
while IFS= read -r newname; do
  printf -v oldname 'lesson%d.mp4' $((n++)) 
  mv -vn "$oldname" "$newname"
done < "/Users/edison/Downloads/movies/list.txt"`

Comment: ...continued...Should I change `newname` to `newname.mp4`? Or do I have to make sure the new titles in the text file look like this: "newFileName.mp4"? I prefer to not have to add that extension because that would need to be done manually. Secondly, luckily I only had two instances, but any title names with a forward slash did not get converted.